# ¿Como saber si un elemento del dom ha cargado con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Como saber si un componente ha cargado, por ejemplo un `div` y no de la forma tradicional toda la pagina `$(document).ready(function() {` usando jquery?

Lo intente así pero no funciona
el div es este

```
<div id="calendar">
</div>

$(document).on('load','#calendar',function(){ 
  ShowMe("¡Procesando su reserva!, favor espere un momento.");      
});
```

Comment: Estás haciendo el `load` al `#edireserva` en vez que al `#calendar`.

Comment: Bueno igual no funciona

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que vas a poner dentro del div y cómo lo vas a hacer? O bien ¿por qué te interesa saber que el div se ha cargado?

Answer (score 2):

El evento que indica que un elemento se ha cargado se llama `onload` en la especificación de HTML y forma parte de los eventos que W3C Recommendation llama [*eventos intrínsecos*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3) y ocurren cuando el agente de usuario termina de cargar:

- la ventana (`window`)
- el documento (`document` o DOM)
- las ventanas `frame` que no tienen `frameset`
- el elemento `body`

Los elementos `div` a diferencia de `document` o de `body` no tienen un envento `onload` que escuchar. Y no lo tienen porque no tiene ningún sentido que lo tengan: cuando haces esto en jQuery:

```
$(function() 
  {
    console.log( "Todo cargado, el div incluido" );
  });
```

Ya tienes un indicador de que el `div` se ha cargado.

Si de todos modos quieres simular una especie de *div ready* puedes:

Recurrir a un atributo `data` que otorgarías al `div` y que *escucharías*  en JS.

Aquí, en vez de `Hola mundo`, podrías incluso poner una función con parámetros y ejecutarla con `eval`. Además, tiene la ventaja de poder recuperar otros datos del elemento, como el `id`.

```js
$('[data-onload]').each(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  var id = elem.prop('id');
  var tipo = elem.prop('nodeName');
  var txt = (tipo == "DIV") ? elem.text() : elem.val();
  var data = elem.data('onload');

  alert("Soy el " + tipo + "  " + id + " | data: " + data + " | texto: "+txt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar" data-onload="Hola mundo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>

<input id="txtNombre" data-onload="enviarInput(this.value)" value="Pedro" />
```

Otra forma sería colocando inmediatamente después del `div` el código Javascript que quieres que se ejecute.

Veamos dos ejemplos, con un código directo, otro llamando una función:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onDivReady(msg) 
  {
    alert(msg);
  }
</script>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("div cargado.... un pseudo div ready");
</script>

<div id="myDiv2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  onDivReady("div 2 cargado.... un pseudo div ready con función");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo estás haciendo mal, el [`load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) de jQuery se utiliza de la siguiente manera:

```
<div id="calendar">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#calendar').load(function() {
    ShowMe("¡Procesando su reserva!, favor espere un momento.");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Esta mal ese codigo Kleith, no funciona, el objetivo que quiero es que antes que se muestre el div me muestre un progressbar y no es tan descabellado como dicen

Comment: Si querés hacer un progress bar entonces lo hubieras aclarado en la pregunta. Leyendo un poco el evento `load()` es sólo para images, scripts, frames, iframes, y el `window` object.